# Grass v.Centerline installation with "No Metadata Available" error

Tags: qgis, grass-7.0

I have Grass 7.8.5 installed and I am trying install the v.centerline extension. I just get a warning with the following, and I see it hasn't installed when going to the Manage Extensions tool.

```
(Mon Mar 15 14:50:32 2021)                                                      
g.extension extension=v.centerline                                              
Downloading precompiled GRASS Addons <v.centerline>...
Fetching <v.centerline> from <http://wingrass.fsv.cvut.cz/grass78/x86_64/addons/grass-   7.8.5/v.centerline.zip> (be patient)...
Updating extensions metadata file...
Updating extension modules metadata file...
WARNING: No metadata available for module 'v.centerline'.
Installation of <v.centerline> successfully finished
(Mon Mar 15 14:50:42 2021) Command finished (9 sec)
```

I installed this as part of QGIS 3.16. What could be the issue/fix here?

Answer (score 0):

When I tried in my **GRASS 7.8.3**, all working okay.

```
(Tue Mar 16 12:21:38 2021)                                                      
g.extension extension=v.centerline                                              
Downloading precompiled GRASS Addons <v.centerline>...
Updating addons metadata file...
Updating private addons metadata file...
Installation of <v.centerline> successfully finished
(Tue Mar 16 12:21:52 2021) Command finished (14 sec)
```

[image]

Are you trying to install it from within GRASS GUI or from commandline? If not from GUI or GRASS commandline, try to install from there which might fix the source repo issue. The only assumptions I can make is either:

- the repository used in your case for this particular extension (`<http://wingrass.fsv.cvut.cz/grass78/x86_64/addons/grass`) is not updated/faulty/missing metadata
- the GRASS version you are using is not compatible with the version of that extension on that repository

In any of the above cases, or if you want to try resolving this issue anyways, if using GUI/GRASS commandline is not helping, you can try installing from different sources using `g.extension`. Please see example below:

`g.extension r.example.plus url="https://github.com/wenzeslaus/r.example.plus" branch=master`.

This has some restrictions on Windows OS where you are only allowed to install from a official repo. Please consult g.extension [manual page](https://grass.osgeo.org/grass78/manuals/g.extension.html) for more specific explanations and examples. Happy GRASSing!

Comment: Thanks. I do get the following error when using your example.

ERROR: Cannot open URL: http://wingrass.fsv.cvut.cz/grass78/x86_64/addons/grass-7.8.5/r.example.plus.zip

Comment: Thanks. What I was suggesting is trying to install from a different repo other than `http://wingrass.fsv.cvut.cz/`. Also you can have more than one versions of grass installed separately, and that way cross-out the probability of version specific problem.

Comment: No luck with 7.8.3 sorry. There is a warning before the addon downloads `There were some issues when loading menu or Modules tab: 
WARNING: List of addons cannot be obtained because g.extension failed. Details: Module run None g.extension --q -ag ended with error
Process ended with non-zero return code 1. See errors in the (error) output` I also tried a couple of other repo's like gitlab but either I have the wrong url or the addon doesn't exist. Would it exist elsewhere?